# Run iisexpress 32 bits instead of 64 bits for debug mode in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, iis, x86, 32bit-64bit, iis-express

I have a web project that references a 32 bit DLL. on IIS i usually set the enable 32 bit applications property on the application pool and it works perfectly. I tried to debug the code locally by running it on iisexpress from visual studio 2015, but i got bad image format exception.

I made sure that "use the 64 bit version of iis express" checkbox in tools->options is unchecked.

I also set the platform target to x86 without luck.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error "Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." is of IISExpress: my PC in 64 bit, but, for some reasons, IISExpress set WCFs as x86 as default.

To solve this error, you could make one registry change if you want to run IIS Express as a 64-bit process by default.

1. Navigate to :Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\WebProjects
2. Make sure there is a REG_DWORD value named “Use64BitIISExpress”.  If not, create it.
3. Set its value from 1 (default = 0).
   [image]

tested with: windows server 2019 64 bit and  Visual Studio 2015

Regards,

Jalpa

Comment: thanks, my case is actually the opposite way around, vs is using 64 bit and i want to use 32 bits. I tried using your directions but instead putting "Use32BitIISExpress" to 1. i also tried putting "Use64BitIISExpress" to 0, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your problem still exists. In VS 2022 you can try to configure debugging (not) to use 64-Bit-Version of IIS Express.

See: Debug > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects > Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects

I'm not sure if it's checked by default in VS2015, but in VS 2022 it is. So just unchecking it helped me out.